# Samba not mounting locations

Tags: 11.10, samba

When I go to the network and I try open a file which is in another computer. The specific location is not mounted and the same problem occurs when other users try to read my files

Answer (score 1):

Wel I resolved my problem by installing `pyNeighborhood` and I mount share folders with that samba client. It's a temporary solution.